How to drive a 4 ohm, 5 watts speaker with the Arduino Uno
I have a speaker written on it "ARTS 4 ohm 5 watt JS52-1251":

I took it from an old sound station whose jack socket no longer works.
I don't have a manual or a datasheet for it nor was I able to find any helpful info online. I wired it to the L298N motor driver (with a power supply of 12V) and to an Arduino UNO but it didn't work. How can I use it with the Arduino? what other electronic components or boards should I use. Do you have any datasheet that could help?

You will need an amplifier circuit: either buy, or build from plans, or design the plans and build. You will also need some way to convert digital output to analog, in the process: Internal or external.

It's a standard 4 ohm 5W speaker, driven like any other similar speaker. The question is, what do you want to do with Arduino and the speaker? Because it determines how to drive it. If you already connected it to a 12V from L298 motor driver, the speaker is likely burnt up now. What did you try to drive to the speaker? What does "it did not work" mean, no sound emitted, something was emitted but not what you expected, like smoke?

@Justme My goal is to play mp3 files, have a button for sound level control, eventually have a audio jack in order to connect a headset. How do I check if it is already burnt up?

@S.E.K. Your Arduino UNO is not powerful enough for playing MP3 files so you need to change the Arduino UNO or your goals. Measure with multimeter how many ohms the speaker is. You might use the UNO to control an MP3 player module or feed MP3 files from SD card to MP3 module, but the speaker will not connect to UNO then.

You need a digital to analog converter (DAC) and an audio amplifier.
Some MCUs and/or development boards have DACs. If yours doesn't, you need to add one. Or some designs use a PWM output and a filter to make a simple DAC.
For an audio amplifier, search for audio amplifier module. Make sure it can drive 4 ohms.

Not necessarily an audio amplifier is required, it depends what the goal is. If the goal is just to drive some beeps and boops, all you need is a transistor on a GPIO or PWM pin.
